# Sidekiq create queue at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am starting to use Sidekiq for a small project.

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a queue at runtime and starting it.

When I use something like

```
Sidekiq::Client.push('queue' => 'anotherqueue', 'class' => TheWorker, 'args' => ['name', 'noname'])
```

The queue is created, but I couldn't find a way to start it.

Comment: this would just create the queue ?
how to enqueue it so that it actually performs the task ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just empty the queue when you first start your app, and as soon as you insert the first item, the queue will start processing. Won't that achieve the same effect?